# Stream vertices from shader into VBO?

Tags: opengl, glsl, procedural-generation

I am trying to implement procedural terrain generation on GPU following [an article from GPU Gems 3](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-i-geometry/chapter-1-generating-complex-procedural-terrains-using-gpu).

I have a general idea how to do most of the things in there, but they talk about streaming the generated vertices to a VBO. Is there even a way to do this in OpenGL?

The section I am talking about is this:

> First, we use the GPU's pixel shader (PS) unit to evaluate the complex density function at every cell corner within the block and store the results in a large 3D texture. The blocks are generated one at a time, so one 3D texture can be shared universally. However, because the texture stores the density values at the cell corners, the texture is 33x33x33 in size, rather than 32x32x32 (the number of cells in the block).
>
> Next, we visit each voxel and generate actual polygons within it, if necessary. The polygons are streamed out to a vertex buffer, where they can be kept and repeatedly rendered to the screen until they are no longer visible.

At first I thought they meant to generate the vertices on CPU, but earlier they write this:

> To build the triangles within this cell, a geometry shader would generate and stream out nine vertices (at the appropriate places along the edges listed)—forming three triangles—to a vertex buffer for storage. Note that the last two int3 values are -1; these values will never even be sampled, though, because we know there are only three triangles for this case. The GPU would then move on to the next cell.

Comment: [Transform Feedback](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback)? Just for the records: GPU Gems 3 is 15 years old. I expect that there are better approaches nowadays using compute shader.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Nowadays a better way would be to use compute shader (instead of fragment or geometry) in combination with workgroup locals (instead of temporary texture) and atomics to output the vertices and the indices into an [SSBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object).

Comment: @YakovGalka Is there a reason for using a SSBO instead of writing to a VBO directly? Wouldn't this make things unnecessarily complicated since I'd have to get the data from the SSBO to a VBO and EBO?

Comment: never mind, I didn't realize you can bind SSBOs as a VBO

Comment: Yes, OpenGL simply has "buffer objects". Those can be bound to different binding points, be it shader storage, uniform blocks, vertex data, pack/unpack, or more. SSBO is a way for a shader to read/write directly to a buffer object.

Comment: @YakovGalka  Since I can't know beforehand, how many vertices the marching cube algo will put out, how exactly would you write the vertices into the SSBO?

Comment: SSBO or not -- you guess an reasonable initial size. If it's not enough, you either accept the glitchy rendering, or allocate a bigger buffer and re-run the marching cubes.

Comment: @YakovGalka I meant if I put an array of floats into the buffer for my vertices. I won't know how many vertices my compute shader will put out for a random voxel. So I can't calculate an array index in my shader, where it should write to. Also I can't know if an instance of the shader will write inbetween the vertices of another, right?

Comment: you use [atomic operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object#Atomic_operations) on the SSBO or an [atomic counter](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Atomic_Counter) to allocate vertices from within the array.

Comment: @YakovGalka Alright, thank you very much for taking the time! You helped me a lot.